# bundledoc problem: \def\input@path does not translate to .dep properly

Tags: input, dependencies, bundledoc

I define the root path for my `\input` files in the `main.tex` files as:

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{ {../fig/} } 
\makeatother
```

When I input a tex file whose address is `../fig/tikz_plots/gaussian_distro.tex` in my document as such:

```
\input{tikz_plots/gaussian_distro.tex}
```

the document successfully compiles without errors. But the file shows up in the `main.dep` file as

```
  *{file}   {tikz_plots/gaussian_distro.tex}{0000/00/00 v0.0}
```

instead of `*{file}   {../fig/tikz_plots/gaussian_distro.tex}{0000/00/00 v0.0}` (which I expect to be the correct one).
Thus, when I use `bundledoc` on `main.dep`, it gives the following error:

```
bundledoc: "kpsewhich -progname=latex $BDINPUTS" (BDINPUTS="tikz_plots/gaussian_distro.tex") failed to find tikz_plots/gaussian_distro.tex
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.